# How to install driver for AMD Radeon HD6470M

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, hd6470m

I've just bought new laptop ASUS K42J with no OS pre-installed. I had installed Ubuntu 10.04 on it. Everything is fine excluding video card performance - it looks like wide screen pulled on horizontal. I had checked monitor preferences - 
there is appears only one resolution 1024x768 4:3.

As far as I understood it a driver's issue. There weren't any problems during installations - open-source driver has been installed automatically. I'd tried to check "additional drivers" section, but it doesn't offer me any additional drivers for installation.

I had downloaded the driver from [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) but now I don't know how to istall it on Ubuntu. I'm newbie on Linux and irt looks a bit complicated for me :)  I tried some tricks mentioned on another posts but with no result.  I'll be very appriciated for any help.

Comment: right click the driver, allow it to execute, then run it form the terminal

Comment: The Radeon HD 6000 series had not been released at the time 10.04 came out.  You might have better luck using a newer version of Ubuntu (the current release certainly does a much better job for my 5000 series card).

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestions. I'll try first to install AMD driver, if will get the same result - then will go to Ubuntu 11.04 and see outcome

Comment: Installation of AMD driver didn't help. I had installed Ubuntu 11.04 and everything woks good now. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open a terminal and change to the directory where the downloaded file has been saved
change to root user

```
sudo su
```

then run the downloaded file(this is the one installed, your version might have another name)

```
./ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run
```

follow the prompts and all should be well

Comment: thanks for your reply. Downloaded driver's file has been saved into "Downloads" directory. The file name is exactly the same like you mentioned. Sorry for a bit stupid question(it's my first steps in Linux) - how I should change directory to root user ? Just by writing "sudo su" ? is that all what have to be written in terminal ?

Comment: once the terminal is open type `sudo su` it will ask for you password enter your password and press enter (nothing will be displayed while you type, this is normal) now you;ll see root@computer-name at the start of you terminal prompt. now type `cd /home/you-user-name/Downloads` and then type `./ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run` and follow the prompts

Comment: thanks a lot, it's very helpful. Now it's cleared for me