# How to install Radeon X600 driver 

Tags: 11.04, ati, multiple-monitors, radeon, switchbox

I am completely new to Ubuntu and now running into so many problems regarding my display.
I will be so grateful to the community to help me out and keep me loving Ubuntu.

When I run

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

I get the following output

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV380 [Radeon X600 (PCIE)]
```

I am not sure if it means the driver is installed.

Now the problem is

1. I can not change the resolution like I can do in windows.
2. I wanted to use dual monitor but it can not detect dual monitor. The monitor option in the preference shows 'Unknown'
3. I tried to use a VGA switch for my ps3 and computer, but the computer is stuck with 1024x768 resolution.

I have been trying for last three days, couldn't figure out anything. Now asking for you wisdom to get my display work.

Regards,
MMRAHMAN

Comment: You can download X600 driver for Linux here :
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English
Then look through installation instructions in this post : http://askubuntu.com/questions/54095/how-to-install-driver-for-amd-radeon-hd6470m
It was helpful for me. Just in your case the name of driver will be ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run

Answer (score 1):

Start by running 'Hardware Drivers' - in Unity, use the search feature in the main system.  The drivers may show up there.  Use the proprietary ones if they exist otherwise use whichever one is recommended.  See if that fixes everything.

Comment: :(no derivers shows up in the 'Hardware Drivers'

Answer (score 1):

If you have been trying for 3 days you may want to invest your time into something else.
I found that out the hard way.  The hardware manufacturers simply don't support their hardware for a really long time.  You may want to try to find an open source driver but again, it depends on how much time you have at your hand.  Another thing to consider is using an older version of the OS that still supports an older stable version of the hardware.  Hope this helps.